# Parse SDK unable to fetch location in background, always time out exception

Tags: android, parse-platform, geolocation

Here is the code I am using :

```
ParseGeoPoint.getCurrentLocationInBackground(10000, new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseGeoPoint geoPoint, ParseException e) {

            if (e!=null)
            Print("location not found " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            else
            {
                Print("location  found ");
            }
        }
    });
```

I have added permissions in manifest both access fine and access coarse location.
Also, is it going to behave differently for android 6.0 with run time permissions.

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.
Thanks