# Android, unable to get current location using Parse SDK, always times out

Tags: android, parse-platform

```
ParseGeoPoint.getCurrentLocationInBackground(10000, new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseGeoPoint geoPoint, ParseException e) {

        if (e!=null)
        Print("location not found " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        else
        {
            Print("location  found ");
        }
    }
});
```

I have added the required permissions in the manifest.
I have also asked this question here [Parse SDK unable to fetch location in background, always time out exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36592307/parse-sdk-unable-to-fetch-location-in-background-always-time-out-exception)

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse SDK unable to fetch location in background, always time out exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36592307/parse-sdk-unable-to-fetch-location-in-background-always-time-out-exception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had to use the default Android apis for getting the user's current location.
Did not find any other solution on how to get the user's location from Parse. Looks like there is no way to it on Parse directly.